# How to load data into multiple tables, using data load feature from oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have two tables, one for the client and one for the client locations.

I want to upload a csv file, using data loading and insert the data into the corresponding tables.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two options:

1. [Oracle Data Pump](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sutil/oracle-data-pump-overview.html) is a command line utility that can load large amounts of delimited text data very quickly.
2. If you have Oracle Application Express installed, you can use the [Data Workshop](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/AEUTL/using-data-workshop.htm#AEUTL244) to load data. This would be quick to use if this is just a one-off data load.